# ¿Como puedo controlar posibles problemas de concurréncia usando ADO.Net y SQLServer?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ado.net

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que sincroniza datos de productos, clientes, pedidos etc de un e-commerce y un SQLServer, lo estoy haciendo mediante ADO.Net.
Esta Base de datos, es de un ERP, por lo que suele haber gente conectada, mi pregunta es:
Pueden surgir problemas si estoy insertando datos a la vez que alguien está haciendo una consulta a alguna de las tablas afectadas?
Gracias.

Comment: Sí, se llama problema de concurrencia y hay varias formas de abordar el tema. Imagina que dos usuarios editan el mismo producto al mismo tiempo, ¿quién gana?

Comment: Ok, gracias, y en el caso de ADO.Net, es una excepción que pueda manejar, o existen herramientas para prevenir estos casos?

Comment: Para prevenir problemas una de las maneras es crear un rowguid, mas info [Merge Replication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/merge-replication?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Miguel recuerda realizar preguntas en base a [ask], saludos.

Comment: Acabo de editar el título, espero que sea eso a lo que te refieres, perdón.

Comment: mira este documento: [acá](https://www.fdi.ucm.es/profesor/fernan/DBD/apuntestema07.pdf) y dependiendo de como necesites manejar la concurrencia es la solución que debes implementar para el aislamiento.